# iTunes column for file location?

Tags: itunes

I'm using the latest version of iTunes (11.0.2) and would like to sort my tracks by their location on my harddrives however I think there is no column for that.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no column for that. And most files are in the iTunes library itself - as it copies them by default.

Comment: I deactived that but see your point.

Comment: I've disabled it myself too for Series and Films, but I cannot locate them via such column as you request too. Unfortunately..